# Upload the same application from 2 different accounts

Tags: ios, app-store

I implemented an application and uploaded it on the app store on my account.
I got the apple reviewers approval and the application is now live on the app store on my account.

However, this application was freelancing and the client wants to create a new account by his name and upload the same application on his account rather than mine.

My question is : Will apple accept this ? 
If yes , is there any problems that might occur to my account ?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new App ID and uploading it? If so what happened?

Comment: @Aaron No I am asking before making new app id , because if I took money from the client to make an app id and then apple rejected the application , I will be in a trouble with the client.

Comment: Transfer the app to your client's account and done.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got the new Account to upload same live application again than you have 2 options :

**1. Remove from old account & Re upload from new account**

- You can Remove the application from the existing account by going to the pricing section & remove the availability. However it will not be permanently removed & will show on your account as a removed app
- After that you can upload from the different account

**2. Transfer App to new account**

- This will be most convenient way to transfer the application
- You just need send the transfer request to the new Apple ID. So it will send request to the new Apple Id
- Once from new Apple ID you accept the request all the data related to the app will be transferred.

[image]

**Suggestion :**

- According to my suggestion the best option is to transfer the application. It will take no longer than 2 minutes.

Hope this will help everyone.